# Excel VBA, compare values in two ddifferent columns and keep entire line for common values

Tags: excel, vba, string-comparison

I have two worksheets with information and I want to compare values in a column from each worksheet and if the values are the same, then I want to copy that entire line that corresponds to a new worksheet.  I currently am using For Next loops but it is very time consuming to run.  Does anyone know a faster method for accomplishing this same task?

```
'compares results and copies entire row with like results to new page
Sheets(2).Select
LR2 = 0
LR2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets(3).Select
LR3 = 0
LR3 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets(2).Select
x = 2
For I = 2 To LR2
CellVal = Cells(x,3).Value
    Sheets(3).Select
    xx = 2
    For ii = 2 To LR3
        CellVal2 = Cells(xx,3).Value
        If CellVal = CellVal2 Then
            Rows(xx).Copy
            Sheets(1).Select
            LR1 = 0
            LR1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1),End(xlUp).Row
            Cells(LR1 + 1, 1).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
            Selection.Columns.AutoFit
        End If
    xx = xx + 1
    Next ii
x = x + 1
Next i
```

Comment: Cycling through cells is very slow. Copy entire column to array and cycle through array instead.

Comment: Instead of your inner ForNext why not consider Finding the value in the inital column. That way you don't need to cycle through each cell in the column.
Your inner routine is basically a custom Find routine, the built-in find routines are much faster.
In addition, are you setting screen updating off? Updating the screen can take a significant amount of time epescially in a nested ForNext.

Comment: Turn off events and screenupdating and see if that speeds it up. It ultimately will, just depends on how much.

Comment: I'm fairly new to VBA so am unsure how I would use an array to accomplish the same task.  Would it be possible to show an example of what the array would need to look like?

Comment: How many columns do you have in Sheet(3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could modify & use the below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Lastrow1 As Long, Lastrow2 As Long, Lastrow3 As Long, i As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim str As String
    Dim rng As Range

    'Set Worksheet' Variables
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws1 = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws2 = .Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Set ws3 = .Worksheets("Sheet3")
    End With

    'Clear Sheet3
    ws3.UsedRange.Clear

    'Find Lastrow of Sheet1 & Sheet2
    Lastrow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Lastrow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop Sheet1, Column A
    For i = 1 To Lastrow1

        'Set str. It's the value in Sheet1, Column A & Row i
        str = ws1.Range("A" & i).Value

        'Use Find Method to check if str apperas in Sheet2, Column A
        Set rng = ws2.Range("A1:A" & Lastrow2).Find(str)

        'If rng in not nothing - Empty (means that str found in sheet2, column A
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            'Find lastrow of Sheet3, Column A
            Lastrow3 = ws3.Cells(ws3.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            'Copy from Sheet1, Column A & row rng.row to Sheet3, Column A Lastrow3 + 1
            ws1.Cells(rng.Row, 1).Copy ws3.Cells(Lastrow3 + 1, 1)
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## Match Copy Paste

You will have to adjust the worksheet names to fit yours. They are now adjusted as you have the indexes in your code: `Sheet(1)` is `"Sheet1"` ...
Using the indexes is quite tricky, so I would recommend you stay away from it.

### What

Compares the values of two columns on different worksheets, and when a match is found, copies the row from one (specified) of the worksheets to a third worksheet.

### How (Not entirely true)

The columns to be matched are copied to two arrays. Then by looping through the arrays, the row numbers of the matches are written to a 3rd array. Then the 'used range' of the source worksheet is copied to a 4th array. Then by looping through the 3rd array (row numbers), each row in 4th array (range) is copied to a 5th array which is then copied to the target worksheet.

### The Code

```
Sub MatchCopyPaste()

    Const cTgt As String = "Sheet1"   ' Target Worksheet Name
    Const cChk As String = "Sheet2"   ' Check Worksheet Name
    Const cSrc As String = "Sheet3"   ' Source Worksheet Name

    Const cFR As Long = 2             ' First Row
    Const cLURC As Long = 1           ' Last-Used-Row Column
    Const cCrit As Long = 3           ' Criteria Column

    Dim rng As Range      ' Last Used Cell of Ranges, Ranges
    Dim vntSC As Variant  ' Source-Column Array
    Dim vntCC As Variant  ' Check-Column Array
    Dim vntTR As Variant  ' Target-Rows Array
    Dim vntS As Variant   ' Source Array
    Dim vntT As Variant   ' Target Array
    Dim SRC As Long       ' Source Rows Count
    Dim CRC As Long       ' Check Rows Count
    Dim TRC As Long       ' Target Rows Count
    Dim STCC As Long      ' Source/Target Columns Count
    Dim i As Long         ' Source-Column Array Row Counter
                          ' Target-Rows Array Row (Element) Counter,
                          ' Target Array Row Counter
    Dim j As Long         ' Source/Target Array Column Counter
    Dim k As Long         ' Check-Column Array Row Counter

    ' Speed up.
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    ' Handle Errors.
    'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' In Last-Used-Row Column (cLURC) of Source Worksheet (cSrc)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSrc).Columns(cLURC)
        ' Create a reference to the Last Used Cell (rng).
        Set rng = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
        ' Calculate Source Rows Count (SRC).
        SRC = rng.Row - cFR + 1
        ' Create a reference to Source-Column Range (rng) calculated from First
        ' Cell (.Cells(cFR, cCrit)), rows resized by Source Rows Count (SRC).
        Set rng = .Parent.Cells(cFR, cCrit).Resize(SRC)
        ' Copy Source-Column Range (rng) to 2D 1-based 1-column Source-Column
        ' Array (vntSC).
        vntSC = rng
    End With
    ' In Last-Used-Row Column (cLURC) of Check Worksheet (cChk)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cChk).Columns(cLURC)
        ' Create a reference to the Last Used Cell (rng).
        Set rng = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
        ' Calculate Check Rows Count (CRC).
        CRC = rng.Row - cFR + 1
        ' Create a reference to Check-Column Range (rng) calculated from First
        ' Cell (.Cells(cFR, cCrit)), rows resized by Check Rows Count (CRC).
        Set rng = .Parent.Cells(cFR, cCrit).Resize(CRC)
        ' Copy Check-Column Range (rng) to 2D 1-based 1-column Check-Column
        ' Array (vntCC).
        vntCC = rng
    End With

    ' Resize 1D 1-based Target-Rows Array (vntTR) to number of elements (rows)
    ' equal to Source Rows Count (SRC), because it cannot have more elements
    ' (rows). Later it will be down-sized (Redim).
    ' Remarks:
    '   In a 2D array, "rows" are the first dimension which cannot be resized.
    '   Target-Rows Array is chosen to be 1D, because only the last dimension
    '   of an array can be resized i.e. the first, last and only dimension
    '   will be elements (rows).
    '   Note: It can be done with a 2D array by writing to the 2nd dimension,
    '     "columns", which would be acceptable even a "must" if it later had
    '     to copied to a range (using Transpose).
    ReDim vntTR(1 To SRC)

'**********************************************************
    ' Since you are writing data from Source-Column Range you wouldn't want
    ' to check values in Check-Column Range that aren't in Source-Column Range
    ' and you would probably want the order of found rows sorted by the
    ' found rows in Source-Column Range, not in Check-Column Range.
    ' If I'm wrong, outcomment these two lines and uncomment the corresponding
    ' lines below, which represent you original loop.
'**********************************************************
    ' Loop through rows (i) of Source-Column Array.
    For i = 1 To SRC
        ' Loop through rows (k) of Check-Column Array.
        For k = 1 To CRC
'**********************************************************
'    ' Loop through rows (k) of Check-Column Array.
'    For k = 1 To CRC
'        ' Loop through rows (i) of Source-Column Array.
'        For i = 1 To SRC
'**********************************************************
            ' Check current value of Check-Column Array (vntCC) against
            ' current value of Source-Columns Array (vntSC).
            If vntSC(i, 1) = vntCC(k, 1) Then ' Matching found.
                ' Increase Target Row Counter (TRC) by 1 i.e. count the number
                ' of elements (rows) in Target-Rows Array (vntTR).
                TRC = TRC + 1
                ' Write current row number (i) of Source-Column Array (vntSC)
                ' to current element (row) (TRC) of Target-Rows Array (vntTR).
                vntTR(TRC) = i
'**********************************************************
                ' If you want to find only the first occurrence of a match,
                ' even better, if you know there is only one occurrence (i.e.
                ' Check-Column Range contains unique values), you
                ' will want to stop looping to increase efficiency i.e.
                ' you have to uncomment the following line.
'**********************************************************
'                ' Match found. Stop looping in rows (k) of Check-Column Array
'                ' (vntCC). Go to next row (i) of Source-Column Array (vntSC).
'                Exit For
'**********************************************************
            End If
        Next
    Next

    ' Resize (down-size) Target-Rows Array (vntTR) to number of elements (rows)
    ' equal to Target Rows Count (TRC).
    ReDim Preserve vntTR(1 To TRC)

    ' In Source Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSrc)
        ' Calculate Source/Target Columns Count (STCC) which in this case (not
        ' always) is equal to the Last Used Column in Source Range, because the
        ' copying later, is done from first column (1, because entire rows).
        STCC = .Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
        ' Create a reference to Source Range (rng) calculated from First Cell
        ' (.Cells(cFR, cCrit)), rows resized by Source Rows Count (SRC),
        ' and columns resized by Source/Target Columns Count (STCC).
        Set rng = .Cells(cFR, 1).Resize(SRC, STCC)
        ' Copy Source Range (rng) to 2D 1-based multi-column Source Array
        ' (vntS).
        vntS = rng
    End With

    ' Resize 2D 1-based multi-column Target Array (vntT) to Target Rows Count
    ' (TRC) for the 1st dimension (rows), and to Source/Target Columns Count
    ' (STCC) for the 2nd dimension (columns).
    ReDim vntT(1 To TRC, 1 To STCC)

    ' Loop through elements (rows) (i) of Target-Rows Array (vntTR)
    For i = 1 To TRC
        ' Loop through columns (j) of Source Array (vntS).
        For j = 1 To STCC
            ' Write from Source Array (vntS), the value in the row which number
            ' is taken from current element (row) (i) of Target-Rows Array
            ' (vntTR), to current row of Target Array (vntT), both in current
            ' Source/Target Array Column (j).
            ' Note: The current element (row) (i) Target-Rows Array (vntTR) is equal
            ' to the current row (i) in Target Array (vntT).
            vntT(i, j) = vntS(vntTR(i), j)
        Next
    Next

    ' In Last-Used-Row Column (cLURC) of Target Worksheet(cTgt).
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cTgt).Columns(cLURC)
        ' Create a reference to the Last Used Cell.
        Set rng = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
        ' Check if Last-Used-Row Column is not empty (Not ... Is Nothing).
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then  ' NOT empty. DOES contain data.
            ' Create a reference to Target Range (rng) calculated from the cell
            ' below (rng.Row + 1) the Last Used Cell in first column (1, because
            ' entire row) resized to the size (TRC, STCC)
            ' of Target Array (vntT).
            Set rng = .Parent.Cells(rng.Row + 1, 1).Resize(TRC, STCC)
          Else                      ' EMPTY. Does NOT contain data.
            ' Create a reference to Target Range (rng) calculated from the cell
            ' in First Row (cFR) in first column (1, because entire row) resized
            ' to the size (TRC, STCC) of Target Array (vntT).
            Set rng = .Parent.Cells(cFR, 1).Resize(TRC, STCC)
        End If
    End With

    ' Copy Target Array (vntT) to Target Range (rng).
    rng = vntT

    ' Apply formatting to Target Range (rng).
    With rng
        .NumberFormat = "0"
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

    ' Inform user that it is done.
    MsgBox "The operation finished successfully.", vbInformation, "Success"

ProcedureExit:

    ' Speed down.
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred. Error '" & Err.Number & "': '" _
            & Err.Description & "'", vbCritical, "Error"
    GoTo ProcedureExit

End Sub
```

### Remarks

The code technically doesn't copy entire rows, it just copies the data of cells from column A to the last column containing data (on the worksheet). If there are thousands of columns there might be a memory issue not to mention if there are tens of thousands of matches.